# spies must be created in a before function or a spec angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have this private function:

```
 private GetChargesByClient(clientId: number): Observable<any[]> {
const ds = new Date();
const dateTocompare = new Date(ds.setFullYear(ds.getFullYear() - 1));
return this.getCharges(id).pipe(map(res => res.filter(x => x.date >= dateTocompare)));
```

}

and I wrote a unit test for it :

```
describe('getAllCharges', () => {
 const _response: any[] =[
    {
        "type": "Ongoing ",
        "date": 1562108400000,
        "totalPayment": "11.54",
        "document": 37
    },
    {
        "type": "Ongoing ",
        "date": 1559689200000,
        "totalPayment": "11.04",
        "document": 37
    }
];

 it('then', (done) => {
      const service: chargesService = TestBed.get(chargesService);
      spyOn<any>(service, 'getCharges').and.returnValue(of(_response));
      const res = service['GetChargesByClient'](130).subscribe(() => done);
      expect(res).toBe(null);
    });
    });
```

but when I run the test I get an error

> spies must be created in a before function or a spec

I have other tests for private methods and they run OK. Can anyone spot anything I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing, `res` will be a subscription object, not the emitted value (so, not null). Another, I'm not sure what's the purpose of `done` here (that might be throwing Jasmine off).

Try

```
it('could use a more descriptive expectation', () => {
    const service: chargesService = TestBed.get(chargesService);
    spyOn<any>(service, 'getCharges').and.returnValue(of(_response));

    service['GetChargesByClient'](130)
        .subscribe((result) => expect(result).toBeNull());
});
```